# Https Post Request with body

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I need to get token from Microsoft AD and for that I need to make a `POST` request with `BODY`. I have this code that returns an error of a missing `grant_type` parameter in body. I guess it's just not sending body. How to configure request to send body?

Any help will be appreciated!

This is my code:

```
var options = {
    hostname:  'login.microsoftonline.com',
    path: '/common/oauth2/token',           
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
    data:{
            grant_type: oauthData.grant_type,
            client_id: oauthData.client_id,
            code: oauthData.code,
            redirect_uri: oauthData.redirect_uri,
            resource: oauthData.resource
         }    
  };

function requestToken(options){
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

        res.on('data', function(d) {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });
    });
    req.end();

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error('---- Error ----');
        console.error(e);
    });
}//end of requestToken()
```

Comment: And what exactly is `oauthData.grant_type`?

Comment: 'authorization_code'

Answer (score 0):

It's not sending the body, because your not telling the req object to.

1. delete the data{} object out of options.
2. add a req.write() to the request.

```
req.write(qs.stringify({ 
grant_type: 'authorization_code',
client_id: config.clientId,
scope: config.scope,
client_secret: config.clientSecret,
tenant: config.tenant
}))
```

Comment: Hi @andrey how did you go here?  Did the answer I provide  point you in the right direction?